# ORACLE XML publishing

Tags: xml, oracle, publishing, oracle11g

I was wondering which tool in ORACLE 11g (their latest DBMS) can be used for publishing XML. I am about to download it but would first like to know the name of the XML publisher and where I could get more information about it from.

Thanks in advance.
S

Comment: What do you mean by "XML publishing"?

Comment: [There a proposal for a dedicated Q&A site for Business Intelligence. Follow, Post and Support to get it up.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70503/business-intelligence?referrer=EPHSm8-3avvaMxLjdRIeNg2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application formerly known as XML Publisher is now called [BI Publisher](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/xml-publisher/index.html).  As such it comes bundled with the  [Oracle Business Intelligence Enterprise Edition Plus](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/bi/enterprise-edition.html) (aka OBIEE).  As the name suggests, this is the BI equivalent of the Enterprise Edition for the database, and requires additional licensing.

As far as I can tell it is not possible to license BI Publisher on its own. However, you can download it under the terms of [the OTN licence](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/popup-license/standard-license.html) from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/publishing/index.html).